# Unable to install any package using apt without the need of an extra package

Tags: apt, dpkg, android-studio

I wanted to install Android Studio. So, I followed this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

But then this started downloading the IDE, which I already had (from Google's official page), so I moved my IDE.zip file to the opt/ directory and ran the above commands again. But it started downloading the same file. So I exited it.

Today, when I tried installing Giggle using this,

```
 sudo apt-get install giggle
```

I am getting the following window. [image: Trying to install Giggle]

And if I press Yes, it downloads Giggle and then starts downloading the IDE all over again.

So, is there any way I can completely remove android-studio and make my terminal forget it ever happened?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 [64-bit].

On a side-note, is there any other way to download things other than apt-get and the Software Center?

EDIT: Added output.

```
lakshya@Inspiron3521:~$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/{giggle,android-studio}*.{post,pre}inst
cat: /var/lib/dpkg/info/giggle*.postinst: No such file or directory
cat: /var/lib/dpkg/info/giggle*.preinst: No such file or directory
cat: /var/lib/dpkg/info/android-studio*.postinst: No such file or directory
cat: /var/lib/dpkg/info/android-studio*.preinst: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 2: I'm getting this red sign on my menu bar now. [image: Red sign on menu bar]

EDIT 3: Result of `sudo apt-get install -f` [image: sudo apt-get install -f].

Comment: Re: side-note: Yes. Open a browser (Firefox comes pre-installed) and download.

Comment: If I download something via the browser, it gives me .tar.gz file and I cannot figure out how to install them. I try using `make` and I always get an error.

Comment: If it helps, whenever I try downloading something, I always get android-studio in the update category, never in the install category.

Comment: @muru, apt-get did not install giggle, it just downloaded it and went right to download the IDE.

Comment: Giggle depends on android-studio? I don't think so because when I try installing `nethogs`, I get the same error

Comment: @muru, [Trying to install `nethogs`](http://i.imgur.com/9dcXGVb.png)

Comment: @Radu, android-studio isn't a dependency, apt is trying to update it. I wan't to stop that from happening.

Comment: What if you remove the PPA? http://askubuntu.com/a/310/158442?

Comment: @muru, [Result of removing PPA](http://i.imgur.com/M75tlhH.png)

Comment: @Radu, I tried putting android-studio on hold, but now when I try installing I get                                                 `E: Can't find a source to download version '4.7-0ubuntu0' of 'android-studio:amd64'`

Comment: @XZYoda12 What is the output of `grep -A1 "Package: android-studio" /var/lib/dpkg/status` ?

Comment: @Radu, 

`lakshya@Inspiron3521:~$ grep -A1 "Package: android-studio" /var/lib/dpkg/status
Package: android-studio
Status: install reinstreq half-installed`

Comment: Ok, then open as root this file: `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and delete all the content referring to `android-studio` package.

Comment: That did it. Now I can install things easily. Thanks a lot. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it accepted?
Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason of your problem is the fact that, as you said, you *exited* before completion from the `android-studio` package installation. So the installation has been unsuccessful. In your case, this can be checked using the following command:

```
grep -A1 "Package: android-studio" /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And probably the output will be something like:

```
Package: android-studio 
Status: install reinstreq half-installed
```

From this output you can understand that the package `android-studio` has been half-installed and now a reinstallation is required.

To fix this you could simply reinstall the package or, if you don't want, then first  make a backup of the dpkg status file by issuing the following command at the terminal:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status status.bak
```

And then open `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file with the following commands in terminal:

```bsh
sudo -i    #  to grant access as root
gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

When it opens, search through the file for `android-studio` package and delete that entry (delete everything from the line `Package: android-studio` until next line that starts with `Package: ...`). Don't delete anything else. Save the file and close it. And in terminal type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to logout from the root account.

Now you should be able to install any other package without the need of `android-studio`.